# Bootstrap 3level menu and delay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I found this solution for 3 level menu for bootstrap: http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html

Its working but has an awful delay when you mouse over on element. Dropdown div still remain visible for 1-2 seconds which is real pain.

My site is here: http://www.mobilecommz.com/gonzabaucc/wp/

Comment: You should post some of there relevant code and provide more detail about the issue, including what you have tried to fix it.

Comment: Just go to this URL -> http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html
hover over dropdown and you can see delay. dropdown remain opened just linke on mine website.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your jquery.smartmenus.js file towards the bottom around line 1110 to 1114 you will see this code

```
    showTimeout:        250,        // timeout before showing the sub menus
    hideTimeout:        500,        // timeout before hiding the sub menus
    showDuration:       0,      // duration for show animation - set to 0 for no animation - matters only if showFunction:null
    showFunction:       null,       // custom function to use when showing a sub menu (the default is the jQuery 'show')
```

See the line hideTimeout: 500, adjust that number lower say down to 200 and you will adjust the timeout delay.

If you take a look at the file comments though you will see that the delay is added for a reason so don't remove it completely

```
// hide with a delay to prevent triggering accidental unwanted click on some page element
```